# Parallel Accumulate

Tags: c++

```
template<typename It>
template<typename It>
std::iter_value_t<It> parallelAccumulate(It begin, It end) {
    static const size_t MIN_COUNT_PER_THREAD = 10;
    const auto size = distance(begin, end);
    std::iter_value_t<It> init{};
    if (size < MIN_COUNT_PER_THREAD) {
        for (; begin != end; begin++) {
            init = init + *begin;
        }
        return init;
    }
    auto const midIt = next(begin, size/2);
    std::future  firstIntervalAcc = std::async(parallelAccumulate<It>, begin, midIt);
    std::future secondIntervalAcc = std::async(parallelAccumulate<It>, midIt,end);

    return firstIntervalAcc.get() + secondIntervalAcc.get();
}
```

Trivial accumulate function just wanted to confirm I am not missing something as new to the language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## The standard library already has parallel algorithms

> Trivial accumulate function just wanted to confirm I am not missing something as new to the language.

Since C++17 you can use [`std::reduce()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce) to accumulate parallely:

```
template<typename It>
auto parallelAccumulate(It begin, It end) {
    return std::reduce(std::execution::par, begin, end);
}
```

## How many threads to use?

The number of threads your function is going to use depends on the size of the input. However, the ideal number of threads to use is actually the number of CPU cores your computer has. Thus, for very large inputs, you could use much more threads than can actually run simultaneously, and then the overhead of context switching might actually slow your algorithm down. Maybe `std::async()` will defer new threads if it detects all cores are already in use, but you cannot rely on that, and even without running them all concurrently, there still is overhead from creating all the futures. Consider limiting the number of threads somehow to [`std::thread::hardware_concurrency()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency).

Another issue is that there is some overhead in starting threads, so if you do too little work in a thread, the time your algorithm takes is dominated by creating and destroying threads. Adding 10 numbers is something that is very fast for a CPU to do, so I would definitely increase that. You might want to benchmark your algorithm with various values of `MIN_COUNT_PER_THREAD` to see what the best tradeoff is.

For some value types, it could be that adding some values is more expensive than adding others. Consider that the value type could be `std::string`, and you have a vector with very long and very short strings. Then some of the async calls might take much longer than others to complete, and this might result in CPU cores being utilized unevenly. A typical solution for this is to have a limited number of threads that continue to pick work to do until there is nothing left to do.

## It can be made more generic

While making the iterator type a template parameter makes your algorithm already somewhat generic, there are lots of cases where it still will not work. Consider:

- The value type not having a default constructor. This is why `std::accumulate()` has an `init` parameter.
- The sum of two values might have a different type than the values themselves, and/or you want to store the result in a different type. Consider wanting to sum lots of 8-bit numbers into a 64-bit variable. This is also solved with an `init` parameter.
- You might want to accumulate with a custom addition operation. The standard library algorithms often have overloads for custom operators.

Comment: Much appreciated, I know there is an existing parallel implementation. I am new to the language so it was more of an exercise to practice the concepts but wanted to confirm it seems ok. Appreciate your feedback I did not think about the last 2 points at all, will revise.

Comment: "the ideal number of threads to use is actually the number of CPU cores your computer has" - assuming there are no other active threads in your program at the time. Executors (think standardized thread pool) are supposed to help with this, but aren't in the standard quite yet.